# Securing GitLab Pages with Let's Encrypt gets 404

Tags: ssl, gitlab, lets-encrypt, gitlab-pages

I am following this tutorial https://about.gitlab.com/2016/04/11/tutorial-securing-your-gitlab-pages-with-tls-and-letsencrypt/
Next step instructions are:

```
Make sure your web server displays the following content at
http://YOURDOMAIN.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/5TBu788fW0tQ5EOwZMdu1Gv3e9C33gxjV58hVtWTbDM
before continuing:

5TBu788fW0tQ5EOwZMdu1Gv3e9C33gxjV58hVtWTbDM.ewlbSYgvIxVOqiP1lD2zeDKWBGEZMRfO_4kJyLRP_4U

#
# output omitted
#

Press ENTER to continue
```

According to the tutorial, it's using Jekyll, but I don't use a static html generator like jekyll. The files are all static html. I created the exact path under root folder: `/.well-known/acme-challenge/PukY0bbiH3nRfciQ4IzwTDIXFn4G5sZ5I-LkMz3-KHE.html`
But after the piplines jobs are done, I am still getting 404. What's the problem here?

Comment: Hi there, did you get any solution for that ? as I am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had problem same yesterday and I found the solution, I hope it is not too late to share with you. According to this tutorial [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/lets_encrypt_for_gitlab_pages.html), the "well-known" folder should be under the "public" folder.

And the letsencrypt need to access a .html file in the following path using the browser.

```
http://YOURDOMAIN.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/5TBu788fW0tQ5EOwZMdu1Gv3e9C33gxjV58hVtWTbDM
```

To do this, you must create the "index.html" file in the path below inside your gitlab repository.

```
public/.well-known/acme-challenge/5TBu788fW0tQ5EOwZMdu1Gv3e9C33gxjV58hVtWTbDM/index.html
```

In the "index.html" file you should put only the following sentence:

```
5TBu788fW0tQ5EOwZMdu1Gv3e9C33gxjV58hVtWTbDM.ewlbSYgvIxVOqiP1lD2zeDKWBGEZMRfO_4kJyLRP_4U
```

**important: do not put any html tag, just the plain text above.**

Then just continue following the tutorial. Good luck.